# how do i delete all relationship of a specific type in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am new to Neo4j // Cypher and I am following the tutorial.
Playing with the movie database i tried to delete all the "ACTED_IN" relationship using the following query

```
match (:Person)-[r:ACTED_IN]->(:Movie)
DELETE r;
```

however i found that i have i still have some "ACTED_IN" relations between nodes and i have to re-run the previous query several times to completely remove those relations.

why is it not working as i expected?
what is the right way to do this?

thanks

Comment: Did you actually use lower case "acted_in" ? Otherwise it should have deleted all in the first run of that query. Which Neo4j version did you use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just tried, it worked for me (Using Neo4j 2.0.1 and 2.1.0-M01)

```
match (:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(:Movie) return count(*);

-> count(*)
   172

match (:Person)-[r:ACTED_IN]->(:Movie) delete r;

-> Deleted 172 relationships, returned 0 rows in 172 ms

match (:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(:Movie) return count(*);

-> count(*)
   0
```

Comment: i just tried to use count(*)...it correctly returns 0 ... then there is probably something wrong with the graph visualization that doesn't updates itself properly.

Comment: i confirm...it's a graphical issue... the graph needs some queries (no matter what they are) to remove all the ACTED_IN relations

Answer (score 0):

To delete all 'follows' relations associated with node with name 'vishal1@myemail.com' :

```
MATCH (n { name:'vishal1@myemail.com' })-[r:follows]->() DELETE r
```

Worked for me :)

Further, you can also specify label(in my case 'User') to distinguish between nodes with same name

```
MATCH (n:User { name:'vishal1@myemail.com' })-[r:follows]->() DELETE r
```

Answer (score -2):

Neo4j Relationshiptypes are case sensitive. So `ACTED_IN` and `acted_in` will act as different relationshipTypes

Comment: yes, i knew...i meant "...i still have some ACTED_IN...". i have edited the post. thanks

Comment: doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @gurel_kaynak check the comment of michael hunger on the question. It was a issue back then that relationships were case sensitive and that could be one of the issues that led to some relations not getting deleted. But it was a issue on visualization end (which got posted later after I posted my solution)